# box-shadow and 100% Fluid Width Issue

Tags: css, width, fluid-layout

I've been polishing up a page I built over the past day or two and have run into an issue after using box-shadow - I was hoping someone might shed some light on an easy way to fix this.

**The Setup:**
I have a div that has a few properties, including width, max-width, and box-shadow.

```
#mydiv {  
       width:100%;
       max-width:1200px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
       box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

**The Problem:**
The "box-shadow" property adds 40px to the width of the div element - 20px on each side. When a screen is small enough that the content should hit the 100% width attribute, we see a horizontal scroll-bar. After digging through the CSS I discovered it was because the div was technically something more like width: 100% + 40px;

**What I've Tried:**
I've considered setting overflow:hidden on the parent div, but I do have a min-width set that would then make content inaccessible. I've also tried using a percentage for the size argument in the box-shadow CSS - 1% for example - and then setting the div's width to 98% - but the box-shadow CSS doesn't seem to accept a percentage for its size. I also have considered using javascript to test the browser width and then display or hide the box-shadow element accordingly, but it doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

There has to be a simpler way to handle this. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't seem to be reproduceable. http://www.jsfiddle.net/xXXLK/1/ (added a height and a background colour).

Comment: It displays for me on your page in the results tab. Its in Firefox 3.6.13 - if width is set to 100% you shouldn't see the shadow at all until after the screen is wide enough that it passes the max-width size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a browser bug.

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow) used to be unclear about this, but wording has since been added to clarify that shadows shouldn't trigger scrolling:

> Shadows do not trigger scrolling or increase the size of the scrollable area.

But as a result of this earlier omission, most browsers *did* trigger scrolling for shadows. This has now been fixed in all recent browsers.

In older browsers, you'll either have to live with the scrollbars, add `overflow-x: hidden` to your `#mydiv` and hope it doesn't break anything, or find another way to add shadows (e.g. using good old PNGs).

Also see the following two related questions:

- [Firefox & CSS3: using overflow: hidden and box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344056/firefox-css3-using-overflow-hidden-and-box-shadow)
- [CSS box shadow on container div causes scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359578/css-box-shadow-on-container-div-causes-scrollbars)

Comment: Thanks for this - at least now I have an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround to the problem of scroll bars in fluid width sites with box shadow.

If you add an @media instruction in your CSS you can detect when the browser window is at a certain width (modern browsers support this and IE9 should too).

For example, for a centered pagewrap div with a max-width set to 940px, try adding this to your stylesheet:

@media screen and (min-width: 998px) {
div#pagewrap {
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 8px 26px #a1a09e;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 8px 26px #a1a09e;
box-shadow: 3px 8px 26px #a1a09e;
} }

The min-width of 998px in the @media css is to make the drop shadow disappear just before it triggers the scroll bar.